# GRPC "Error: 12 UNIMPLEMENTED: RPC method not implemented" even if service exists, in nodejs-apps behind docker network

Tags: node.js, grpc

two node apps interacting with eachother, using grpc to talk to eachother, unpredictably stop communicating and erroring with above line. 'Error: 12 UNIMPLEMENTED: RPC method not implemented /servicename/methodname' as one of them restarts.

A little help in understangind this issue from anyone who has seen such situation would be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: Are u saying that your communication works but stop working unexpectedly? Is the server still working? Are u able to connect again? Please add more details to your question

Comment: Sorry for late response, 
@AlexsandroSouza 
Yes, the communuication works initially. then stops working unexpectedly after long time as one of the servers restart for update.
- both servers still work after this issue,  one of them keeps receiving 'service not found' / 'rpc method unimplemented' issue .. 

only way to get them to connected to eachother is to restart both of them once of twice